# Unity ButtonComponent. Error adding delegate to OnClick event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

MyCode:

```
[SerializeField] private Employee[] employees;
[SerializeField] private Transform uiList;
[SerializeField] private GameObject logPrefab;

private void OnEnable()
{
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        
        var obj = Instantiate(logPrefab, uiList).transform;
        var button = obj.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Button>(); //button = 0
        button.onClick.AddListener(delegate () {employee.Upgrade();});
       
        var nameText = obj.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>(); //button = 0
        nameText.text = employee.Name;

    }
}
```

Unity does not display errors and the code below performs good (the text changes on new logs):

```
var nameText = obj.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>(); //button = 0
nameText.text = employee.Name;
```

The whole problem is that the delegate is simply not added to the list. Nothing happens when pressed.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Do you have a debug log in the `Upgrade()` function to confirm it isn't executing?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest few changes to your code which will help you.

```
[SerializeField] private Employee[] employees;
[SerializeField] private Transform uiList;
[SerializeField] private Log logPrefab;

private void OnEnable()
{
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        
        var log = Instantiate(logPrefab, uiList);
        var button = obj.Button;
        button.onClick.AddListener(employee.Upgrade);
       
        var nameText = obj.Text;
        nameText.text = employee.Name;

    }
}
```

Place this script in separate file named Log.cs.
Add this script to your prefab and assign references in inspector to your `Button` and `TextMeshProUGUI` (and do not forget to set reference to this prefab into script above):

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Log : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Button button;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public Button Button => button;
    public TextMeshProUGUI Text => text;
}
```

### So what happening here?

I remove unneeded delegate creation from `AddListener`

old:

`button.onClick.AddListener(delegate () {employee.Upgrade();});`

new:

`button.onClick.AddListener(employee.Upgrade);`

I introduce class Log to avoid expensive `GetComponent<...>()` and inaccurate `GetChild(...)`. For instancing, I'm using `Instantiate<T>` ([info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) - just scroll down to see how it works)

### In the end

If, it's still not works, please check following points:

1. you have `EventSystem` in scene
2. you have `GraphicRaycaster` on your Canvas (where you have your buttons)
3. you have `NewInput system` enabled in project, follow these instructions for [migration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.8/manual/UISupport.html)

Comment: Just fyi you can even reduce it a bit and use `[field: SerializeField] public Button Button { get; private set; }` .. matter of taste of course but then you have half of your code in the `Log` ;) ... I would probably also rather call it `LogVisuals` or `LogEntryVisuals` to be as clear as possible

Comment: @derHugo the problem with `[field: SerializeField]` that Unity not officially support this (it works but could have limitations) so it could be detrimental for new users.

And name `Log` were taken from field name of prefab so @GedJack will have better understanding what this script does